# ListPicker FullMode Wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I try to open a listpicker programmatically in full mode, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
        picker.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        picker.ListPickerMode = ListPickerMode.Full;
```

Has someone an idea how to open a selection page, like that of the ListPicker programmatically? Or do I just use the wrong control for such a behaviour?

Comment: I don't think the ListPicker control supports being opened initially in full mode because it actually navigates to a separate page to show the list in full mode. What are your actual app requirements for this scenario?

Comment: The user selects a menu item (let say: open details), than a selection page should open. The problem is, that I have a dynamic range of selectable items (e.g. the listpicker page would be ideal). After user selection, a new detail page should open.

Comment: So you just need a page of dynamic options, then? In which case just implement a page with a ListBox and bind the items accordingly.

Comment: Thought there might be a possibility to skip implementing a page .. :(, but guess I will do so. Thx for the hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListPicker control does not support being opened in FullMode initially. It implements the full mode by using a separate pages and handling the navigation to/from it for you. If you simply need a full-screen list of options, then you will need to implement a similar page yourself. You might find the [source code](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61620#) for ListPicker useful.